# m3u8 sound lost due to seekTo()

Tags: android, audio, streaming

I have the source code of an app that plays *.mp4* and I have to make it works with HLS.

The video and the sound are played but I have 2 problems ONLY WITH .m3u8 :

1) When *seekTo()* is activated (commentaries deleted) the sound is disabled and when I want to quit the player, it makes a long time to do and it makes crash the app.

2) setLooping doesn't work and return **Error (-38,0)**, Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong

`state: mPlayer=0x1e0380, mCurrentState=0`

Note: those problems are just for .M3U8

Below code of the player :

```
private void playVideo() {
    doCleanUp();
    try {
        // Create a new media player and set the listeners

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(mFilePath);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);       
        mMediaPlayer.prepare(); 
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        //mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        //mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mResumePosition);
        //mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        showErrorMessage(mErrorPlayingVideo);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Impossible de jouer la vidÃ©o",
        // 5000).show();
    }
}
```

Logs when setLooping is activated under setDataSource() :

```
error (-38, 0)
prepareAsync called in wrong state 0
prepareAsync_l return error =-38
error: null
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)
at fr.niji.broadpeak.activity.BroadpeakDemoPlayer.playVideo(BroadpeakDemoPlayer.java:409)
at fr.niji.broadpeak.activity.BroadpeakDemoPlayer.onRequestFinished(BroadpeakDemoPlayer.java:585)
at fr.niji.lib.dataproxy.service.DataManager.handleResult(DataManager.java:262)
at fr.niji.lib.dataproxy.service.DataManager.onRequestFinished(DataManager.java:292)
at fr.niji.lib.dataproxy.service.ServiceHelper.handleResult(ServiceHelper.java:297)
at fr.niji.lib.dataproxy.service.ServiceHelper$EvalReceiver.onReceiveResult(ServiceHelper.java:119)
at android.os.ResultReceiver$MyRunnable.run(ResultReceiver.java:43)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and below the code :

```
Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x1e0380, 
mCurrentState=0
error (-38, 0)
Error (-38,0)
Error (-38,0)
Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x1e0380, mCurrentState=0
Error (-38,0)
Error (-38,0)
Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x1e0380, mCurrentState=0
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the problem. When you use seekTo() with a .m3u8 file and the value between the parentheses is set to 0, it doesn't work so I added a condition into playBackVideo() method :

`if (mResumePosition > 0) mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mResumePosition);`

So mResumePosition will never be set to 0 and play at the beginning of the file. Also, i resolved the setLooping() problem, in

`public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)`

I added `mMediaPlayer.release(); playVideo();`

and the looping works very well !

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it is the LIVE case. If Yes, Looping and seeking might not available.

Comment: Ok I found the problem.

When you use seekTo() with a .m3u8 file and the value between the parentheses is set to 0, it doesn't work so I added a condition into playBackVideo() method :

`if (mResumePosition > 0)
         mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mResumePosition);`

So mResumePosition will never be set to 0 and play at the beginning of the file.

Also, i resolved the setLooping() problem, in `public void onCompletion(final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)` I added `mMediaPlayer.release();
        playVideo();` and the looping works very well !